# Every step must define a `uses` or `run` key GH actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to setup yaml file for github actions. However I am not sure what am I doing wrong, I've added uses and run for every step but it still throws the error.

I am getting the following error:

```
every step must define a `uses` or `run` key
```

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  ios:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps: 
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: '2.8.1'
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter build apk
      - name: Install pods
      - run: cd ./ios && pod install
      - name: Run fastlane
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
- name: Install pods
- run: cd ./ios && pod install
```

It should be: (remove "-" before run)

```
- name: Install pods
  run: cd ./ios && pod install
```